# Matlab subplot linkaxes is not lining up the axes as expected

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot, axes

I can't seem to get `linkaxes` to work (code is below). I am trying to get the subplots to line up, such that visually the x-axis is has the same range and width for both subplots. The misalignment is in both the pop-up figure window and the saved JPG. Using Matlab R2018a.

Here is my code, and below is what the figure looks like:

```
x1 = [27247 26973 27265 28924 27182 27430 26534 26839 7876 26484 29787 26934 27218 25777 27801 8250 34820 7980 26927 34639];
y1 = [-2350 -3334 -2948 -2336 -2778 -2813 -3383 -3635 -31 -3334 -4216 -3284 -2271 -2477 -2058 375 -821 351 -3441 -1108];

ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
scatter(x1, y1)
box on
grid on
axis equal
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim')
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Exponent = 0;
ax.YRuler.Exponent = 0;
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim')
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
scatter(x1, y1)
xlim(xlims)
box on
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Exponent = 0;
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x')
```

I've also tried this (below), but it doesn't change the plot.

```
% adding this to the first subplot:
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim')
positioning = get(gca,'position');
% adding this to the second subplot:
xlim(xlims)
set(gca, 'position', [positioning(1) positioning(2)/5 positioning(3) positioning(4)]) %x y width height
```

And here is what the figure looks like:
[image]

Comment: It's been too long since I last did this and cant find the code I had. Are you writing your article/report in latex anyway? Maybe use subtable in latex instead?

Comment: @Argyll, the workflow needs to be done in Matlab, this is part of a much larger analysis

Comment: I tried your code with MATLAB 2018a and 2019a, I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Problem also not reproducible on MATLAB 2017b, both subplots align perfectly in the popup figure and the saved jpeg file.

Comment: Tried in MATLAB 2019a Update 3 (Linux). Could repeat the problem. It becomes more clear when one increases the window size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved on the Matlab forums, and here is a summary/application of the solution:

```
x1 = [27247 26973 27265 28924 27182 27430 26534 26839 7876 26484 29787 26934 27218 25777 27801 8250 34820 7980 26927 34639];
y1 = [-2350 -3334 -2948 -2336 -2778 -2813 -3383 -3635 -31 -3334 -4216 -3284 -2271 -2477 -2058 375 -821 351 -3441 -1108];

ax1 = subplot(2,1,1);
scatter(x1, y1)
box on
grid on
axis equal
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim')
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Exponent = 0;
ax.YRuler.Exponent = 0;
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim')
ax2 = subplot(2,1,2);
scatter(x1, y1)
xlim(xlims)
box on
grid on
ax = gca;
ax.XRuler.Exponent = 0;
set(gcf,'Resize','off') %%%%%%%% this line fixes it for some reason!
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x') % want to link x-axis only

%figOut = 'test';
%print(figOut, '-r300', '-djpeg')
```

[image]